# boost::function memory usage

Tags: c++, performance, boost, memory-management, boost-function

I'm considering using `boost::function` in my implementation of a timer manager. At schedule timer a `boost::function` will be passed and at the timer expiration the callback will be executed. Times will be scheduled/canceled at a vey high frequency (~1000 actions/sec).

But I'm concerned regarding the amount of heap memory `boost::function` may use.

I know for example that `boost::asio` uses `boost::function` a lot, while performance requirements for the library are probably very high.

What do you  think?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/fastdelegate2.aspx), might give you some perspective.

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely in my opinion that the overhead of `boost::function` will be the gating factor in timer management code.

Getting the timer queue, locking and signalling waiting threads correct and efficient is a much better use of your brain cycles.  Perversely, that's another argument *in favour* of `boost::function` or similar to avoid headaches with 'raw' callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

boost::function is a fairly small object.  Might be all of 2-3x the size of a normal function pointer, if any.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the size of allocated data, but rather about new/delete itself

Comment: @dimba - you are going to have to `new` something to track pending timers anyway, if you are careful the functor memory can be included in that can't it?

Comment: @Steve I don't sure I understand what you mean. User will have API like ScheduleTimer(boost::function<>, ...), so boost::function<> already allocated by user. Can I do it different way?
I'm using 3rd pary library for timer managment (ACE) which enables to store void* for each active timer, so I'll need to store store pointer to boost::function<>. Can I use it somehow to prevent some memory allocation?

Comment: In that case, you should be able to either share the user's copy, or else copy it, but the user will not need their copy any more.  This is a wash, whichever way you look at it - net effect = 1 functor on the heap during timer handling.  I just wondered if you could include this in the timer correlation structure, to avoid using a heap-based struct that has a pointer to functor.